# What's wrong with my while loop in Client?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, loops, printwriter

I've got problem with loop. In my project I'm sending a comments from match through socket.
I know that something is wrong with one of my loops because in client last comment is still printed.

```
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while(true){
        out.println(rel.getCommentary());

        }
```

getCommentary is a method with present comment from JTextField

Client's loop

```
        in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());          
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            showCommentary(in.nextLine());
        }
```

Server GUI

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object source = e.getSource();

        if(source == addComment){

            String comment=commentField.getText();
            rel.setCommentaryText(comment);  
            panel4.setBackground(Color.green);

        }
```

Client

```
private void showCommentary(String text){
    showArea.append(text+ "\n");
    showArea.setCaretPosition(showArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

Relation class

```
public class Relation{

    String relation;

    public Relation() {

    }

     public void setCommentaryText(String relation){
         this.relation= relation;
     }

    public String getCommentary(){
        return this.relation;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the input and the output you are getting.

Comment: Why are you using loop on server site for printing ?

Comment: I add my actionPerformed

Comment: @SergiiZagriichuk it makes that server is still checking a new commentary from method

Comment: @Dominik you have the answer, but my comment was like hint for your problem, BTW your solution can work with loop but your method should move your loop-thread to wait mode and notify it if new message will appear, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in `Server`, you should have a method that will print commentary:

```
public void printCommentary(String commentary) {
    out.println(commentary);
}
```

In `ServerGUI`, when you set the commentary:

```
if (source == addComment) {
    String comment= commentField.getText();
    //call the server's print method we just wrote, only once, no loop!
    server.printCommentary(comment);
}
```

Your bug is that the `while(true)` loop is executing all the time. It prints to outputstream your last commentary forever. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: In server I'm using rel.getCommentary() from Class Relation where I setCommentaryText(). In serverGUI I've got rel.setCommentaryText(comment); where I set text from commentField

Comment: So I think I dont need another method in server or am I wrong

Comment: You are wrong. You don't need a `while(true)` loop for sending in server, but a method that does it once, just like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: hmmm, could U look at my all Server. http://pastebin.com/R0uwy6mk sorry for variables :( How can I start method printCommentary in my case?

Comment: Okay, I've edited it a bit. Take a look at the clientThread code and try it. http://pastebin.com/EiusjB5y

Comment: Having fixed that, I see no point in having the `clientThread` class at all because the Client is not sending anything! Just receiving. All sending could be done from the `Server` with a method I wrote you in the answer.

Comment: Sorry if I again bother You, but I've got a little problem with update my serialized objects. I guess I should create another loop in Client but it still dont update. Could You just take a look at my client code  http://pastebin.com/S7YQ4qZ5 :)

Comment: You need a `while(true)` loop around `Pakiet p = (Pakiet) ois.readObject(); and it should end (`}`) before the `catch` clause.